# how to "connect ipv6 client to ipv4 only server"

Tags: ipv6, tunneling

I have a linux server that supports only ipv4 and an IPv6 client. How should I use tunneling or NAT to get the connectivity done from ipv6 client to the ipv4 server? Client is a softphone that sends register requests to server and server has ipv4 address

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that, it are two different protocols. You can tunnel through IPv4 and IPv6, but you can not get an IPv4 address to talk to an IPv6 address. Beginning and end point need to be the same protocol.

You have two options, either use IPv6 on your linux machine (you can use [SIXXS](http://www.sixxs.net/)) or provide IPv4 connectivity on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most useful solution would be to deploy a DNS64/NAT64 box at the edge of the IPv6 network. This will NAT the IPv6 client to IPv4 so it can reach the server. You need to be in control of the client's network though...